# Objective-C valueForKeyPath performance vs looping

Tags: objective-c, performance, loops

Does anyone know what's the performance difference between using valueForKeyPath with collection operator vs looping the collection one-by-one and manually does the calculation? For example:

```
NSSet* myObjects = [NSSet setWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
NSNumber* sum = [myObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.myProperty"];
```

vs

```
NSSet* myObjects = [NSSet setWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
int sum = 0;
for(MyObject* obj in myObjects)
    sum += obj.myProperty.intValue;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that `valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.myProperty"` will summ up the integer values (as opposed to, say, doubles?)

Comment: I believe it returns NSNumber, but the example here assumes all values involved are int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your question is based on a misunderstanding of the common use of collection operators. The common use is for Core Data, where the data can be accumulated more efficiently in SQL without having to fault the entire object.

In my experience, simple loops are much faster for in-memory `NSSet` or `NSArray` backing stores.

Comment: the original purpose of the function was to sum values from Core Data objects that were connected via a relationship.  Assuming all the objects in the set have been faulted and in memory already due to previous function calls, would the looping and valueForKeyPath approach yields similar performance?

Comment: You should test against your specific situation. It is not a hard A/B test. If you can guarantee that there will be no faults or any other side behavior, then it should not be controversial that a simple loop will always be faster than any other solution. In practice, it is sometimes hard to guarantee that for large data sets (and for small data sets, it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that the first implementation is faster because one classic implementation of a set is through a hash map based on the key, thereby making the lookup by key an O(1) algorithm vs. your manual O(n) implementation.

This being said, there's nothing better than a quick experiment. Load up your NSSets with thousands of values and see which one is faster.

Comment: The first snippet isn't a lookup, there's a loop somewhere in its implementation :):):)

Comment: The desired result here means that any procedure will have to go through all the objects in the set -- there's no way to make it _less_ than O(n).

Comment: Agree with John. You could keep a running tally as objects are added to avoid a potentially large summing routine later on, but you have to access every object in order to add them together.

Comment: This assumes the backing store is an in-memory collection. These are not the only kinds of collections. Core Data may not have all of its information in memory, so faulting all the data may be very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Under my test conditions with a set of ten million members, I found that the second method, the simple loop was faster -- 0 seconds vs 32 seconds.  With a million members it was 0 seconds vs 3 seconds.  This does assume all the data is in memory, and agrees with Rob Napier's experience. Here is the test code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSMutableSet *testSet = [NSMutableSet set];
    int i = 0;
    while (i <10000000) {
        [testSet addObject:[[TestObjects alloc] init]];
        i++;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]);
    NSNumber* sum = [testSet valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.myProperty"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]);
    NSLog(@"%@",sum);

    NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]);
    long long sum2 = 0;
    for(TestObjects *obj in testSet)
        sum2 += obj.myProperty;
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]);
    NSLog(@"%lld",sum2);
    NSLog(@"%ld",testSet.count);
}
```

And the TestObject had just this in the init:

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.myProperty = arc4random() %100;
    }
    return self;
}
```